# appwidgetprovider can implement onactivityresult how can use it?

Tags: android

i need to use onactivityresult on appwidget but how i can use it ? its not called

public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider implements
        OnActivityResultListener {
    Context context;

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    this.context = context;
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.PARCELABLE_WRITE_RETURN_VALUE);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.activity_main);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton1, pending);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {}
```

Comment: There is no `startActivityForResult()` in this code.

Answer (score 0):

`onActivityResult()` is only available on `Activity` and its subclasses. That is because `startActivityForResult()` is only available on `Activity` and its subclasses.

Comment: @user2130760: You can't. Your code clearly will not compile. Beyond the fact that the `@Override` will fail, you are defining a method that returns `boolean`, yet you lack a `return` statement, so that will raise a compiler error as well.

Comment: so how i can use contact of phone on widget
how i can use contact number in widget with out activity like my code

Comment: @HiTaX: I have no idea what you mean by "how i can use contact of phone on widget how i can use contact number in widget". There are many Android developer support sites. Perhaps one is in a language that is more comfortable for you. I have several listed at http://www.andglobe.com.

Comment: i need to use widget to select a contact and use number of contact how can do it ?

Comment: @HiTaX: Have the app widget display an activity. Have that activity allow the user to pick a contact, then use the resulting data.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have same issue, I want to start an activity from AppWidgetProvider class.  In activity class ,after completed a thread which is started by the Activity, get result back to AppWidgetProvider class, How can i achieve this task.